# Java process hang in a short time

Tags: java, vmware

I run my application on a VMWare Linux guest, and it doesn't work well.

I write another simple counter to run on the same guest for testing.
(add counter every 0.5s)

Counter works fine while application stop,

but shortly hanged while appliction is running (marked time and numbers).

```
  10:21:24.386 : 166
  10:21:25.154 : 167
  10:21:25.971 : 168
  10:21:25.971 : 169 <--
  10:21:26.957 : 170
  10:21:26.957 : 171 <--
  10:21:27.848 : 172
  10:21:27.885 : 173
  10:21:28.776 : 174
  10:21:28.884 : 175
  10:21:30.374 : 176
  10:21:30.374 : 177 <--
  10:21:30.379 : 178
  10:21:31.264 : 179
  10:21:31.380 : 180
  10:21:32.155 : 181
  10:21:32.933 : 182
  10:21:32.933 : 183 <--
```

counter code shows below, but I don't think theres problem

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
        int i=0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + " : " + i);
            i++;
        }
    }, 500, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Here's the top result while application is running

```
top - 11:02:49 up 20:49,  5 users,  load average: 12.87, 14.66, 13.22
Tasks: 196 total,   5 running, 190 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu0  : 77.3 us, 20.5 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.3 si,      0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 82.4 us, 16.5 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16267652 total,  7639820 free,  7309136 used,  1318696 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  8257532 free,        0 used.  8588648 avail Mem
```

It seems my application running out of resource and making JVM working improperly ?

Except for adding more resource to guest, is there any ways to reduce resource consuming?

Using jmap -histo to find mostly used object and check it ?

Hers's enviroment info

java version "1.8.0_181"

CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

VMware 6.0

Comment: Maybe garbage collector kicking in? But what exactly is your question to us?

Comment: You should run a Profiler, and analyse exactly what is going on in your application. It's impossible to tell what's slowing it down without a tool and knowledge of what your code does.